# Android : the mystical technique to set different dimensions for different device / screen sizes

Tags: android

My first Android App. And, am trying to get this sorted -> setting different text sizes, layout sizes for different screen / device sizes. Now,  I Googl'ed a lot , then read several Stackoverflow threads, & am doing this:
Created different folders under 'res' like
values-ldpi
values-mdpi
values-hdpi
values-xhdpi
values-xxhdpi
values-xxxhdpi

Then I put a dimens.xml & styles.xml in each folder above.

Phew! But this doesn't suffice. I want to have different textsizes (and other dimensions, am not speaking about images here) for phones & different ones for tablets. I know there are these 'values-sw600dp, and 'values-sw720dp' which they say is aimed at tablets. But even within each tablet size, I need to differentiate the different densities right? For example, within 'values-sw600dp', I need to have different textsizes for, say, hdpi, xhdpi, ... How do I do this? Any help please?

Here is an example of what am doing:

```
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_interference);
    textView.setHeight(layoutHt);
    textView.setWidth((layoutWd-20)/2);
    int dimensControlButtonTextSize = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.CONTROL_BUTTON_TEXT_SIZE);
    textView.setTextSize(dimensControlButtonTextSize);
```

Then in dimens.xml, it would be:
    17

This value, i.e. 17 here, will differ in each device i.e. it is given a different value in each dimens.xml under each values- folder. I hope am clear.

Comment: Why are you doing anything besides images using densities? There's a reason `dp` exists.

Comment: these folders are for dimes.xml ad styles.xml, not for images. So my question is about setting dimensions & styles, @ianhanniballake

Comment: Yes, can you give examples of what dimensions and styles you are changing based on density? Those things don't usually change by density.

Comment: @ianhanniballake text sizes change based on density right? for example, I have a 'settings' button. The text 'settings' in the button appears larger in devices with small densities & smaller in devices with higher densities

Comment: Text sizes are usually in `sp`, which automatically takes care of being the same physical size no matter what density the screen is. Again, include an example of what you are doing.

Comment: @ianhanniballake added an example. Thank you. Are you sure 'sp' is enough to handle the cases? I thought we need to explicitly give the values in dimens.xml for each screen size.

Comment: Wait, are you declaring dimensions as integers? Can you also include one of your dimens.xml files?

Answer (score 0):

Drawable resources do not need to be duplicated per screen configuration, except for special cases like you have a full screen splash that would be displayed differently for landscape and portrait. Normally for icons, specifying once in the main resources folder (under hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi...) should be sufficient.

I would find screen configuration specific resources to be useful for `dimen` values, like padding, margin, width of items, etc...

Comment: my question is not about images. it's about setting dimensions & styles for different device sizes & densities.